# Prove the derivative vanishes given a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

Suppose f is strictly increasing and continuous everywhere. Suppose further that $a_n$ is a increasing sequence and $b_n$ is a decreasing sequence both tending to $x$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}=0}$ . Is it true that $f'(x)=0$ ?

Comment: How can $f$ be strictly increasing and $f'(x)=0$ at the same time?

Comment: consider f(x)=x^3

Comment: Oh thought by strictly increasing you meant $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I mean the following $x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)$

Comment: This is sort of like $ f'(x)= \lim\limits_{h\to0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{(x+h)-(x-h)}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: Choose a positive sequence $c_1 > c_1^2 > c_2 > c_2^2 > c_3 > … \to 0.$ On each $[c_n^2, c_n],$ define $f = c_n^2.$ It might be good to draw a picture right bout now.

Define $f$ on each $(c_{n+1},c_n^2)$ by joining the horizontal steps with a line segment. So far we have an increasing, but not strictly increasing, function on the interval $(0,c_1].$ Let's continue this debacle by setting $f(x) = c_1^2, x > c_1,$ and $f(x) = 0, x\le 0.$ So $f$ is increasing on all of $\mathbb R.$

Set $b_n = c_n, a_n =-c_n.$ Then

$$\frac{f(b_n) - f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n} = \frac{c_n^2}{2c_n}= \frac{c_n}{2} \to 0.$$

But

$$\frac{f(c_n^2) - f(0)}{c_n^2-0} = 1$$

for all $n.$ It follows that $f'(0)$ cannot be $0$ (and in fact, doesn't exist).

Now to find a strictly increasing counterexample, consider $f(x) + x^3.$

Comment: I must say I didn't expect this at all, you can even modify your example to be Lipchitz, right?

Comment: Yes, looks like you could keep the Lipschitz constant under 2 or something.